# Libgdx Google Play services crash

Tags: libgdx, google-play-services

Hey guys I had this problem for a while now, hope some one could help

*Im using eclipse luna

*Using LibGDX

*My app have ads

In a few devices my app crash, in the other majority it works fine, crash log is the following:

```
09-11 19:31:59.656: E/AndroidRuntime(7022): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-11 19:31:59.656: E/AndroidRuntime(7022): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap
09-11 19:31:59.656: E/AndroidRuntime(7022):     at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzs.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

I had search for this problem and found that some people suggest to add `android-support-v4.jar`

Well, i did add it like this... I dragged `android-support-v4.jar` into lib folder of `project-android` project

Then I right click the android project 
properties->java build path->Libraries->Add Jars then in here I added the jar file I put in lib folder

Now it wont even compile:

```
[2016-09-11 19:33:41 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536 
[2016-09-11 19:33:41 - proyecto-android] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try importing the following as given in [Guide in GitHub](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples):

- Import the Google Play Services library project (available for download through the SDK manager):

  1. Click **File | Import | Android | Existing Android Code into Workspace**
  2. Select `SDK/extras/google/libproject/google_play_services/google_play_services_lib` (where `SDK` stands for the path where you installed your Android SDK)
  3. Click **Finish**
- Import eclipse_compat/libraries/BaseGameUtils as a library

  1. Click **File | Import | Android | Existing Android Code into Workspace**
  2. Select the `eclipse_compat/libraries/BaseGameUtils` project
  3. Click **Finish**
  4. Right-click on `BaseGameUtils`, then click **Properties**
  5. In the project properties window, click the **Android** section
  6. Check the **Is Library** checkbox
  7. Add a reference to the `google_play_services_lib` project (click **Remove** to remove any broken references, then click **Add** to add the correct one)
- Import the desired sample from the `eclipse_compat` directory (Project | Import | Android | Existing Android Source)
- Go into the project properties window for that project (right-click, **Properties**) and check that this project has a reference to the `BaseGameUtils` project.

If it still doesn't work for you, you may want to try going through [Tutorial: Set up Google Services with LibGDX](http://fortheloss.org/tutorial-set-up-google-services-with-libgdx/) for the complete guide. Hope it helps!